# I want to use JSForce to create a custom field on the Contact Object using the metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, custom-field, standard-objects, jsforce

I am trying to use code like this to create custom fields on the Contact Object in salesforce using JSForce. This does not work of course and the documentation does not show how to do this with standard Objects. It also does not show you how to create different field types either.
[enter link description here](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#metadata-api)

```
 // creating metadata in array
var metadata = [{
  fullName: 'Contact.TestObject1__c',
  label: 'Test Object 1',
  label: 'Auto Number #2',
  length: 50

}];
conn.metadata.upsert('CustomObject', metadata, function(err, results) {
  if (err) { console.err(err); }
  for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var result = results[i];
    console.log('success ? : ' + result.success);
    console.log('fullName : ' + result.fullName);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSForce is just a "wrapper" for the metadata API (another other APIs). To use it, you need to specify a smorgasbord of options depending on what you're doing with the field. You will want to refer to the [CustomField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm) documentation, since there's a large number of parameters available. You should start off like this:

```
var metadata = [{
    fullName: "Contact.FieldName1__c",
    label: "Field Name 1",
    type: "text",
    length: 80,
    inlineHelpText: "Text that appears in the ? next to a field.",
    defaultValue: "A default formula can be here."
}];
```

The exact options you need will depend on the type of field. Formulas require different parameters than text fields, lookup fields require different parameters than number fields, and so on. Everything you need is in the documentation.

Comment: I am getting this error using the code above `soapenv:Client: Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}length invalid at this location in type CustomObject`

Comment: @IOG IT should be `CustomField`, not `CustomObject`. `conn.metadata.upsert('CustomField', metadata, function(err, results) {`